# Bundle product on cart shows up price 0 (REST API)

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, bundle-product

I'm using Magento 2.3 as a headless solution, having an Angular app as a storefront  and using REST API to manage eCommerce functionalities.

The fact is, in certain conditions, a bundled product with fixed price, have a 0 price after being added to the cart.

I'm working with guest carts and the flow is like the detailed below:

- POST /rest/V1/guest-carts
- POST /rest/V1/guest-carts/{{quoteId}}/items

  ```
  {"cartItem": {
      "sku": "bundled-product", 
      "qty": 1,
      "quoteId":"quoteId", 
      "productOptions": {
          "extensionAttributes": [
              "bundleOptions": {...}
          ]
      }
  }}
  ```
- In this moment, the cart shows up the inserted product with its correct price
- DELETE /rest/V1/guest-carts/{{quoteId}}/items/{{itemId}}
- POST /rest/V1/guest-carts/{{quoteId}}/items (with the same previous product)
- In this moment, the cart shows up the inserted product but with price 0

Have anyone faced this problem/issue? Have anyone resolved or fixed? Am I making something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some intensive research and test a lot of sugestions, there's a workaround to fix that:

Editing `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Repository.php` to add these lines in the `save` funciton (before `$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);` ), everything goes ok:

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2991

Comment: never ever edit vendor files

Comment: You are righ @PhilippSander. In a happy scenario it shouldn't be necessary. But if you have read the linked issue, you would realize that there is a PR waiting for merging for several months and none of the Magento CE mantainers have merged yet.

I'm sure that there will be another more elegant solution for this, but as I said, it's a workaround not a solution, that's the reason for the answer has not been marked as a solution.

Comment: don't even try to justify... editing vendor files is bad. why not use a plugin?

Comment: As I said, you are right, a vendor file has not be editted under any circumstance, I agree with that.

I use Magento as a base, my goal is not to develop over Magento, just use it as a backend for our headless solution. 

I think using a plugin to fix a bug (that has been detected on 2.1 version and it has not been fixed yet) is not a proper solution for a project as big as Magento CE is, but it's my opinion.

At the end of the day, I've posted the root of the problem in order to others could adapt a solution (plugin, fork, whatever they think it's the best solution) to fix it.